# How to push/sync tickets between Trac instances/projects?

Tags: trac

Does anyone know how to push tickets from one Trac instance to another?

The problem that I'am trying to solve is the following:

Our company is doing some development for big international firm (let's call it CompanyX) that has everything behind VPN's. We have our Trac, hosted at our firm, which we use for management of all our projects. CompanyX also uses Trac, and since the developers from CompanyX cannot use our Trac for tracking bugs, requests and issues, they use their own. The reason is that their security policy is very restrictive with no Internet access to our server, and nothing can be done about that.

The problem is that we are also forced to use THEIR Trac because they prefer to communicate everything through it internally, and they expect from us to conform to their workflow as well. And for that purpose we have to connect to their VPN via some IE java plugin client from Juniper (which does not remember passwords) and every time have to configure whatnot, just to see a ticket or two on weekly basis which is really tiresome.

Since the communication is mainly one directional, from client to our firm, with no real interaction, I was wondering is there an EASY way to just push (or even sync) the tickets and their updates from client's Trac to our Trac server which would satisfy their outsourced security provider?

(It is not possible for us to touch the Trac's source on their server, so by EASY, I mean some plugin or script or something similar which would be easily accepted by their admin)

Answer (score 1):

There is [TicketImportPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketImportPlugin) that can import tickets from csv or excel files. The opposite is to export tickets as csv or tsv files via link on the bottom of a ticket page.

[TicketMoverPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketMoverPlugin) is able to move tickets from one Trac instance to another.

Comment: TicketImportPlugin would be helpful if we find a simple way for their Admin to export them as a CSV first. After that, the Admin would probably agree to push CSVs via FTP to our server, with or without VPN. Any idea how to export in a way that does not result in Admin telling us to bugger off ("not possible because of security reasons")?

Comment: I don't know an other way than clicking the export link at the page bottom. I just found this related request which may help you also: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/10699

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something using the [XMLRPC plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin).  You can script up an application that queries your client's Trac for tickets (using `ticket.query()`), then grabs the ticket details (`ticket.get()`) and posts them to your Trac in a new ticket (`ticket.create()`).

This would require both Trac instances to install that plugin and create a trac account that has the `XML_RPC` permission.  You will have to make sure that your client finds this acceptable.  Since it's a pre-packaged plugin that you can enable on a per-account basis, it shouldn't disrupt their normal workflow very much.

Comment: I think we will use jira and collect issues via regular email notification or something like that. Their policy is too restrictive for anything meaningful.